# In "A Farewell to Arms" wouldn't Earth be destroyed instead of Mars in the parallel universe?

Tags: futurama

In the episode "The Farnsworth Parabox" everything that happens in the regular Futurama universe happens the opposite in the other parallel Futurama universe. So if Mars got destroyed in the regular Futurama universe wouldn't Earth be destroyed in the parallel universe and Mars would be saved?

Comment: Why wouldn't it merely be Mars didn't get destroyed?

Answer (score 7):

No, the difference between the two universes was that specifically *coin flips* have the opposite outcome in the [parallel universe](http://theinfosphere.org/Universe_1), not just every binary possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is  no, because the difference between our universe and the parallel universe is the outcome of the coin flip. Furthermore Mars never got destroyed in the episode Farewell to Arms. Instead it just became a huge satellite of Earth, so even if in one of the parallel universes all the thing are the exact opposite to our universe the Earth wouldn't be destroyed but probably froze since it would change orbit and move next to Mars.